# How can I organize my code so that it's neater?

Tags: python, performance, reorganize

```
from subprocess import call
command = input(': ')
if command == '1':
    call('notepad.exe')
elif command == '2':
    call('calc.exe')
else:
    print('command not found')
```

I have similar code except it's a lot more if statements. Main objective here is to make it take up less space / make it more organized. I am unsure of how to proceed with such task.

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. create a dictionary of commands:

```
menu = {'1': 'notepad.exe', '2': 'calc.exe'}
```

Then you can use:

```
command = input(': ')
if command in menu:
    call(menu[command])
else:
    print('command not found')
```